# I'm trying to make a call from a run file to model method

Tags: ruby

[link to the models](https://github.com/JasKomal1/barber-project/tree/master/app/models) The error I'm getting is the cli app is shutting down when I type y

```
def see_barbers 
puts "Would you like to see your barbers y/n"
answer = gets.chomp
if answer.downcase == "y" 
  @user.barbers.all.name  #so I'm sure this line is written wrong just not sure how to fixit
else 
  puts "ok what else"
end
```

end

Comment: would be great if you could add more info like the user model and the barber model, how they are related etc

Comment: Thank you so much the pluck method made it work. ps added a link to the models if you still wanted to take a look, sorry about the lack of detail in the original question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have an array of something and you want to call a method on each thing in that array and group together the results the typical approach is to use `map`, as in:

```
@user.barbers.all.map(&:name)
```

If you've already loaded all of these records then this is fine, or if you have just a regular Ruby array of objects.

That this is really inefficient since you're loading every record, picking out just the bits you want, and throwing out the rest. This is like ordering a hundred salads just to pick out the tomatoes.

There's a method called `pluck` for ActiveRecord which can extract *just* the data you want, like:

```
@user.barbers.pluck(:name)
```

Where that does, effectively, a `SELECT name FROM ...` to get only the data you require.